# Sakila Schema is not Imported to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Problem to import the Sakila Database in Mysql5.0.51b.
The specific problem is in the 'DELIMITER SYNTAX', I have tried some alternatives but didn´t works.

I use APPServr.

MYSQL MESSAGE ERROR:

```
    --
-- Triggers for loading film_text from film
--
DELIMITER;


MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

DELIMITER CODE:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `ins_film` AFTER INSERT ON `film` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description)
        VALUES (new.film_id, new.title, new.description);
  END;;


CREATE TRIGGER `upd_film` AFTER UPDATE ON `film` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (old.title != new.title) OR (old.description != new.description) OR (old.film_id != new.film_id)
    THEN
        UPDATE film_text
            SET title=new.title,
                description=new.description,
                film_id=new.film_id
        WHERE film_id=old.film_id;
    END IF;
  END;;


CREATE TRIGGER `del_film` AFTER DELETE ON `film` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM film_text WHERE film_id = old.film_id;
  END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with `APPServr`, and would suspect it for twisting some commands before sending over to MySQL (this is not an accusation, merely a suspicion).

I have successfully imported the `sakila` database numerous times in classroom. The best way, in my opinion, is to simply `SOURCE` it from the `mysql` command line client:

```
mysql> SOURCE /path/to/sakila-schema.sql
mysql> SOURCE /path/to/sakila-data.sql
```

Otherwise you can import via command line from shell/Command:

```
bash$ mysql < /path/to/sakila-schema.sql
bash$ mysql < /path/to/sakila-data.sql
```

And also, using MySQL Workbench I've evidenced no problems with this.